# How to access array of python in JavaScript from Views in Django?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, view

I am writing this array in Views in Django:

```
address=["Main Address"]
```

and passing in dic. and accessing in Java Script in HTML page:

```
address={{context.lat_long.address}}
addMarker(address,{lat: property_lat, lng: property_long}, "red");
```

But it is not working at all

Comment: I would expect quotes `address='{{context.lat_long.address}}';`

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how Django templating works.
The template data (Jinja) are generated in the backend, before sending the page.
The JS code is runing in the front.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following way,
In django views,

```
address=["Main Address"]
return render_template('page.html', address=address)
```

In the page.html and the attached javascript, you can access the variable as,

```
var a = {{ address }};
```